# SQL server 2016 restore impact of mirroring configuration?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

We have Windows Server 2016 and on it SQL server 2016 standard edition is installed. Another windows server 2016 machine has mirroring of SQL server configured.

Lets call Primary SQL server as A and Mirrored SQL server as B.

ON A we will delete DB and restore from some existing backup.

My question is do I need to recreate mirroring configuration between A & B?

Comment: If you delete the Primary database on A and it is restored, this is equivalent to breaking the mirror where you would need to reconfigure mirroring from A to B.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just delete or drop db when mirroring is configured. You have to remove mirroring `alter database dbname set partner off`.

Then drop database on primary.

Then restore from the desired backup.

Then reset up mirroring - take full and log backup and restore it to server B with NO_RECOVERY.

**Remember :** Mirroring is deprecated technology. So you should either use basic availability group or if you are on Enterprise edition then go with AlwaysON.